# The cookie is deleted when the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, next.js

I have an api in express that sends a jwt to my application in next.js through a cookie but when receiving it is saved, but when reloading the page the cookie is deleted I did the process locally and if it works but when I put it in production that happens to me.

I'm a bit new to this and I don't know what I'm missing.

Fetch Login

```
export const getUser = (username: number, password: string): Promise<Login[]> => {
    const url = `https://192.168.1.25:9000/auth/login`;
    const body = { username, password };
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
    }).then((res) => {
        return res.json()
    });
};
```

Login Endpoint Express

```
export const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const cookies = cookieParser();
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        console.log(username, password);
        const result = await query(`SELECT T0."email", T0."U_ESSI_contrasena_essisoft" AS "contrasena", T0."govID" AS "id", T0."firstName" AS "nombre", T0."lastName" AS "apellido"
        FROM "PRUEBA_INV_NOVEMBER"."OHEM" T0
        WHERE T0."govID" = '${username}'`);
        if (result.length > 0) {
            const user = result[0];
            if (user.contrasena !== password) {
                res.status(401).json({ message: "Incorrect User" });
            }
            const token = jwt.sign({
                username: username,
                password: password,
            }, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
            // enviar el token en las cookies cuando la conexion es insegura
            res.cookie('token', token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: true,
                sameSite: 'none',
                domain: '192.168.1.25',
                path: '/',
                expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)

            });
            res.status(200).json(user);
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({ message: "Incorrect User" });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
}
```

It should be noted that the backend and frontend are running on the same server and have the same ip but listen on different ports.